# No module named 'tensorflow_datasets.image.cityscapes'

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, tensorflow2.0

I installed TensorFlow Datasets using conda, as:

```
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-datasets
```

I've tried importing Cityscapes:

```
from tensorflow_datasets.image.cityscapes import Cityscapes
```

but this raises the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_datasets.image.cityscapes'
```

How can I fix it?

**PS:** I can import the following without errors:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
```

---

Edit:

I've already downloaded Cityscapes data, as recommended in the [official guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/cityscapes).

Comment: The cityscapes database has to be downloaded manually here: https://www.cityscapes-dataset.com/downloads/

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) Yes, I followed the official guide and downloaded the data, already (I will clarify this in the question).